# How to stop/abort/cancel a page load in PhantomJS?

Tags: request, phantomjs, html, abort

I use PhantomJS to check a list of links for specific content. Once these content is found I would like to cancel the page load to avoid further ressource requests and continue with the next page to improve speed.

I filter requests in page.onResourceRequested and request.abort(); everything that doesn't match but that doesn't prevent PhantomJS from requesting till the site finished.

Tried page.stop(); -> crashes PhantomJS

The documentation seems lacking and I wonder if there is a command I can use to do that.
I can't use page.close(); because I need the page object after the content is found.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can cancel ongoing requests, but you can prevent new requests with `request.abort()`. Doesn't this work?

Comment: I thought request.abort(); only cancels the ongoing request, not all further requests?

Comment: It can definitely cancel *starting* requests (before any data is even put on the wire). I don't know whether it can abort requests where the client is waiting on the response from the server.

Comment: But I want to cancel the whole page load at once, at the moment I cancel every request that doesn't match with request.abort(); but if I find my ressource there is no need to load the site any further.

Comment: I would think that you can keep track of all currently ongoing resource requests and once you want to stop the page load, you may set a global variable to abort *all* new requests and then iterate over the array and abort all ongoing requests. That is my idea, but as I said, I have no idea if it can work.

Comment: any one found the solutions for this?

Comment: @iyyapan yes, I use this: page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) { var matchUrlNeeded = ((/someregexforurl\/js/g).test(requestData.url)); if (matchUrlNeeded) { doStuffWithTheUrl;                         response.close();
                        request.abort();
                        page.cancel(); } } else {
                    //console.log("NO MATCH : " + requestData.url);
                    request.abort();
                } { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) {
    var matchUrlNeeded = ((/someregexforurl\/js/g).test(requestData.url));
    if (matchUrlNeeded) {
        doStuffWithTheUrl;
        response.close(); 
        request.abort();
        page.cancel(); }
    }
    else {
        //console.log("NO MATCH : " + requestData.url); request.abort(); } { }
```